# Like static resource, is it possible to serve JSPs which are placed out side of webapps

Tags: jsp, struts2, tomcat8, static-content

I am using Struts2 in my application with Tomcat.

I am serving static resource of my application by placing them outside of webapps with setting in `server.xml`.

Now I have to serve JSPs in same way, which are outside of  my context. Is it possible? Or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: @AleksandrM I want to convert single tenant application to multitenant and some tenant have custom JSPs.

Comment: What do you mean by custom JSP? Do you want to change pages dynamically?

Comment: No, not dynamically. In webapps there are default jsps available. But some JSPs are customized to override default one. So I used to over write them in single tenant application. now the picture is different in multitenant..

Comment: How? Why can't you put other jsp-s along with the *default* ones and use others for some users?

Answer (score 1):

You can place JSPs anywhere, but the web application should be aware of the location of the resources.

Since you didn't pointed where exactly you want to store JSPs, I couldn't tell you how to do that. I can say that resources are retrieved via `URL` in Java, if you can point the server to some URL where resources are stored, then you can access these resources.

If you need to learn more about how in Java accessing resources you can read [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

> #### Resources, names, and contexts
>
> A resource is identified by a string consisting of a sequence of
>   substrings, delimited by slashes (/), followed by a resource name.
>   Each substring must be a valid Java identifier. The resource name is
>   of the form `shortName` or `shortName.extension`. Both `shortName` and
>   `extension` must be Java identifiers.
>
> The name of a resource is independent of the Java implementation; in
>   particular, the path separator is always a slash (/). However, the
>   Java implementation controls the details of how the contents of the
>   resource are mapped into a file, database, or other object containing
>   the actual resource.
>
> The interpretation of a resource name is relative to a class loader
>   instance. Methods implemented by the `ClassLoader` class do this
>   interpretation.

---

The difference between static resources and dynamic resources:

- static resources could be run directly by browser
- dynamic resources (like JSPs) are run on server.

Don't confuse loading dynamic resources the same way as static resources, because the static resources could be returned with the response, but dynamic resources should be returned to the server.

Comment: you can consider JSPs are on the same machine where my web application running, but out side tomcat installation directory.

Comment: not related but you know what is it a web application context?

Comment: I am not getting your question

Answer (score 0):

JSPs get compiled into servlets (hence java classes) that are executed by a JSP container using a fairly complex life-cycle, which you can read about here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_life_cycle.htm

So the short answer is: no.  You can't serve JSP pages outside your web app, since one of the primary functions of that web app is to compile and execute JSPs.

As the other answer suggests, you can access java resources using a variety of mechanisms, but you are always going to need something that looks like a JSP container to render JSPs.

You'll have to move onto a different technology if you want to serve more of your app from something like a content delivery network.

You might look into creating a purely client side app that talks to the back end via REST, graphql, or web sockets.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Content you edited is not clear to me.

Comment: Can you explain internals of tomcat, how tomcat treat JSPs in web applications? how it serves in response. I am very well aware of life cycle and all that.